# I can't get cas overlay build with jdbc dependency

Tags: jdbc, build, overlay, cas

After successfully building cas overlay for v5.3.9 with static authentication, after adding the dependency for jdbc the build fails.

The only difference from the basic build is adding the dependency to pom.xml (as per the documentation):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There is no indication in the documentation that I should need any authorization to access repository contents

### Maven build results as follows:

```
/NetBeansProjects/cas-overlay-template-5.3; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.1 /opt/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn clean install
Scanning for projects...

---------------------< org.apereo.cas:cas-overlay >---------------------
Building cas-overlay 1.0
--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from shibboleth-releases: https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.pom
Downloading from shib-release: https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.pom
Downloading from shib-release: https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/nimbusds/lang-tag/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from shibboleth-releases: https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/nimbusds/lang-tag/maven-metadata.xml
Could not transfer metadata com.nimbusds:lang-tag/maven-metadata.xml from/to shibboleth-releases (https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not transfer metadata com.nimbusds:lang-tag/maven-metadata.xml from/to shib-release (https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project cas-overlay: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apereo.cas:cas-overlay:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc:jar:5.3.9 -> org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-authentication-api:jar:5.3.9 -> org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-api-events:jar:5.3.9 -> org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-util-api:jar:5.3.9 -> org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:jar:3.6.1 -> net.shibboleth.tool:xmlsectool:jar:2.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.shibboleth.tool:xmlsectool:jar:2.0.0: Could not transfer artifact net.shibboleth.tool:xmlsectool:pom:2.0.0 from/to shibboleth-releases (https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with a fresh clone of `5.3.9` branch and adding just the jdbc dependency. Check for conflicting dependencies or include your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks leopal - I tried a fresh clone of that branch, added only the jdbc dependency to pom.xml, and got the same error. The only possibly pertinent info not included in my initial post is I'm running macOS 10.14.5 (Mojave). Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Mac to test.

Comment: @CraigS, I saw that you have the error of `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`, this is very likely a bug related to self-signed certificate. Pretty sure you are using this overlay here `https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/5.3`, if so, please try use `./build.sh gencert` to gencert, so the self-sign cert is correctly imported. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Ng Sek Long. I went through replacing the cert, following the code in build.sh - no joy, same problem.

Comment: Found it! Silly me, I naively added the jdbc dependency to pom.xml under the comment "...Additional dependencies may be placed here...", when, in fact, it needed to go in a different <dependencies> section. It's really frustrating when documentation is so vague, like 'add this line of code' - to what file? And where in some file? Thanks to all who took a look for me!

Comment: Well, no, that wasn't it (dependency decl in wrong place). CAS 5.3 with jdbc dependency won't build on mac os 10.14. I tried with 5.2, built and ran successfully 1st time.